Why does Ramayan and Mahabharat are present in different religions like Buddhism, Jainism and Kabir panthis
Why does Jainism, Buddhism and Kabir panthis and some other religions have their own versions of Ramayana and Mahabharata where they have shown their own deities as Supreme instead of Sri Rama and Sri Krsna rather in some versions Sri Rama and Sri Krsna are portrayed very nadly why is that and Buddhism , Kabir panthi etc also claim that all great saints like Tulsidas ji, Mirabai etc converted to their religion at last. What is the truth I can't understand. Pls help me

They just write their own versions of Ramayana and Mahabharata to promote their own ideas.

But how can they write such voluminous scriptures with detailed story
